# Can the person who buys my old number access my old Viber contacts?

Tags: security-by-design

I was using Viber on my old phone. I stopped using that SIM card/number and stopped using that phone. I forgot to deactivate my Viber account. When my old SIM card carrier sells my old number to a new person, does that person access my Viber contacts and people I was talking to?

Comment: Welcome to the site! That sounds like it may be a question for the particular application. But generally, applications that use your phone number as the only format of authentication could be abused in this way.

Comment: Thanks. Please look at the answer and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the platform works similar to WhatsApp or Signal Private Messenger. Viber should only use your phone number as a unique identifier, and no content (contacts or messages) should be stored on the server side.

This seems to be [confirmed by Viber](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/2810857-back-up-and-restore-viber-messages-#back-up-messages) such that message backups are done through a cloud service; Google Drive or iCloud. Also, [Viber uses end-to-end encryption](https://www.viber.com/blog/2018-01-28/your-data-is-protected-with-viber/), so their servers cannot see the content of messages, only metadata.

Consequently, if someone does receive your old phone number, no messages can be seen (as no content is stored by Viber), and the same is applicable to contacts.

Comment: Thanks. How can I verify your answer for sure?

Comment: @Jack Put your SIM card in a new / formatted phone, and install Viber.

Comment: Also, on viber you have an option to see associated devices with your account, and you can deactivate them.

Comment: Thanks. But I've lost my old SIM card now.

Comment: I emailed viber support. They said this:

"Thank you for contacting Viber support.

Please be advised that every account activation deactivates Viber from previous devices and a new activation sets up a new account. No previous data will be available for a new owner of your previous number.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Best Regards,"